# gem install psych error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psych

I'm trying to bundle install a rails project but I'm stuck...
when I try to run `gem install psych` all I get is this:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing psych:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/gibatronic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h is missing. Try 'port install libyaml +universal' or 'yum install libyaml-devel'
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/gibatronic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
    --with-libyaml-dir
    --without-libyaml-dir
    --with-libyaml-include
    --without-libyaml-include=${libyaml-dir}/include
    --with-libyaml-lib
    --without-libyaml-lib=${libyaml-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/gibatronic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/psych-1.3.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/gibatronic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/psych-1.3.4/ext/psych/gem_make.out
```

I'm running `ruby 1.9.3p327` with `rails 3.2.12` on `OS X 10.8.2`

I've already installed `libyaml 0.1.4` with `rvm pkg install libyaml`

I really don't know what to do anymore!

Comment: its looking for the libyaml-devel lib, try installing that as it is suggested in the error message

Comment: I would like to @bernabas but it seems that libyaml-devel doesn't even exists!

Comment: this just worked for me `port install libyaml +universal` @gibatronic

Comment: yeeesssss! thanks @bernabas! I didn't knew MacPorts... now that I installed libyaml through it I could finally install pysch gem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

install libyaml

```
port install libyaml +universal
```

Answer (score 11):

```
apt-get install libyaml-dev
```

did the fix in my case running under Debian 7 based systems (Likely the same for Ubuntu)

Comment: It says it is already the newest version

Comment: Can't believe this fix still works almost 10 years later. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

macOS:

```
brew install libyaml
```

It fixed my `gem update` error on trying to parse YAML step.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev
```

But I don't know why? can some explain what this command does.

Answer (score 2):

Windows:

Run **Windows PowerShell as Administrator**, then type the command:

```
gem install psych
```

(if you run PowerShell in administrator mode, it will not display
privilege issue when installing dependencies for psych, so libyaml
will be installed and the message "error: cant lock database / Could not create Makefile" will not be displayed)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to set the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS variables:

```
# ensure libyaml is installed
port install libyaml +universal

# if you like you can check the location of the installied files (especially the .h file)
# port contents libyaml

# now configure with these options
CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include/ "  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib/" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```